# Replace word text with excel percentage value via VB returns text value on mac

Tags: macos, vba

I have following part of the code which replaces word text with value from excel:

```
.Replacement.Text = exlDoc.Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(row, column)
```

Excel values have General or Percentage format. On Windows, this works as expected, percentages are replaces as e.g. 5.54% while same code on Mac returns 0.0554. How can I format it to work on both Mac and Windows and to be working for all formats.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could change the number format in code.

```
ActiveCell.Numberformat = ??Percent
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.Replacement.Text = exlDoc.Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(row, column).Text
```

`.Text` is a read-only property of the cell.